# Connecting to MySQL db in microk8s cluster using workbench

Tags: linux, docker, devops, microk8s

Can you help me with accessing MySQL db that I deployed in microk8s cluster using MySQL workbench.

I tried to create ingress and access it using the hostname and I couldn't access the db in that way.

How can I do this. Please help me

Comment: Impossible to tell without knowing what you did. Please, as a new user here, start with the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In general, Ingress services are used to expose HTTP/HTTPS traffic and won't be useful for exposing your MySQL database. The simplest solution is probably to expose MySQL as a [NodePort](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#type-nodeport) service, which would open a port on all the worker nodes.

When using a NodePort service, you can select a specific port (from the NodePort range, typically 30000-32767) to use for the service (otherwise you'll get a random port which probably isn't all that useful).